# Efficiency in algorithm exercise

Tags: algorithm, performance

What does "The algorithm should be a form of binary search for efﬁciency" exactly mean? I have written an home-work code for an algorithm the way it was asked to, but in the end, one sentences asks for the algorithm to be a form of binary search for efficiency...
Does that mean to keep the complexity equal to a binary search's?

Comment: Yes. The homework probably expects O(log(n)) execution time.

Comment: Maybe it's telling you to modify/employ a binary search (presumably because such an approach already has decent complexity for the given problem) .. but I'm not the TA :)

Comment: That's really a question for your professor. If he intended for you to implement binary search, and you simply implemented something with similar runtime complexity to binary search, you'll have a problem. We're programming professionals, not "figuring out what your professor meant" professionals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it means that in order to be efficient your algorithm should implement binary search.

```
Algorithm needs to be what?  form of binary search
For what purpose? for efficiency
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes that means to have a complexity comparable to binary-search's complexity ie, O(lg(n)). Basically what that line means is that you have to do something which reduces the computation to half of its original state at every step. So, if 1 is the amount of computation required at initial step then, 1 becomes 1/2 then 1/4 then 1/8 and so on with every step.